# Modify output of pandas day_name() function

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame with `df` name :

```py
>>> df.head()
```

|  | InvoiceNumber | ProductCode | InvoiceDate | UnitPrice | CustomerId | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 489434 | 85048 | 2009-12-01 07:45:00 | 6.95 | 13085 | United Kingdom |
| 1 | 489434 | 79323P | 2009-12-01 07:45:00 | 6.75 | 13085 | United Kingdom |
| 2 | 489434 | 79323W | 2009-12-01 07:45:00 | 6.75 | 13085 | United Kingdom |
| 3 | 489434 | 22041 | 2009-12-01 07:45:00 | 2.1 | 13085 | United Kingdom |
| 4 | 489434 | 21232 | 2009-12-01 07:45:00 | 1.25 | 13085 | United Kingdom |

I want a bar plot of my data frame based on number of sold product in each day of week, like this :

[image]

I'm use this code :

```py
fig1 ,ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 6))
df["dayName"] = pd.to_datetime(df["InvoiceDate"]).dt.day_name()
df.groupby("dayName").size().plot(ax=ax1, kind="bar", color="lime");
```

and i get this plot :
[image]

I'm have 2 problem : 
1- name of days is not short (Monday : Mon) 
2- weekdays are not ordered 
Any body can help me to solve this problems ? 
Thanks

Comment: I want order by standard weekdays that start from Monday, not alphabetize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution can be, Use of [`pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html)*(The day of the week Monday=0, Sunday=6.)* Then use `.set_xticklabels` to assign the name of day week to the number.

```
df["dayName"] = pd.to_datetime(df["InvoiceDate"]).dt.dayofweek
df.groupby("dayName").size().plot(ax=ax1, kind="bar", color="lime");
ax1.set_xticklabels( ('Mon', 'Tue','Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun') )
```

Output: *(Generate from random input)*

```
[Text(0, 0, 'Mon'),
 Text(1, 0, 'Tue'),
 Text(2, 0, 'Wed'),
 Text(3, 0, 'Thur'),
 Text(4, 0, 'Fri'),
 Text(5, 0, 'Sat'),
 Text(6, 0, 'Sun')]
```

[image]